# Replace photoswipe plugin share icon

Tags: css, svg, photoswipe

I'm trying to replace the existing share icon in [photoswipe](http://photoswipe.com/) (an arrow) with something more self-explanatory like the picture attached. Since I don't know how to edit the original SVG sprite I took an other approach which is to replace this piece of code:

```
.pswp__button--share {
  background-position: -44px -44px; }
```

by this code:

```
.pswp__button--share {
  background-image: url(http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/fbshare.png);
}
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work (the image is not visible at all), would you know why?

The new icon:

[image]

Tks

Comment: Are the sizes the same?

Comment: Height, yes. Width no.

Comment: Need more info then.  "Doesn't work" doesn't give us much to go on.

Comment: The image is not visible at all actually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this css (You need to change size and positioning, since it doesn't have the same size as the other buttons):

```
.pswp__button.pswp__button--share {
  /*Not sure that was your image but you can adapt it to any image you want*/
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmjUo.png);
  width: 167px;/*width of the image*/
  /*Positioning*/
  background-size: auto;
  background-position: 0;
}
```

I created a working example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpKVQP

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately your codepen does not seem to return the expected results (I tried with firefox and chrome, and I see multiple buttonsin double or triple)

Comment: @Greg My bad, the css selector was not specific enough for some devices. I updated my answer accordingly. :)

Comment: Hi Alouro, seems that nothing happens when I click on the new button (it doesn't open-up the sharing options like it used to do with the "old/original" button). I suspect this is due to the fact that you created a new class... Any way to obtain the same result without creating a new class? Many thanks

Comment: Hey @Greg, if you want to reuse the same default share button behaviour, you can actually just use the css in my updated response (see codepen).

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey, me again! Is there a solution to make the picture retina-compliant? I created a version with 2x the size but as you can see here http://s24.postimg.org/r8qoj161x/socialshare.png the result is not OK (because we're using background-image I assume). Tks

Comment: Hi @Greg, whenever you have a problem with CSS, I would suggest playing around with the chrome inspector to live edit the CSS, and trying to figure out what the problem is.
I find that this is one of the best way to learn CSS on the spot ;)


In css, if your background-image is bigger than the element to which it is applied, you should change the background-size to the wanted smaller size.
In your case I guess it should be `background-size: 167px 22px;` instead of `background-size: auto;`